# Relationships query in Tableau Metadata API by using GraphQL

Tags: c#, graphql, tableau-api, tableau-prep, tableau-cloud

In Tableau Metadata API by using GraphQL, I can able to extract all information's about the Datasource, but I couldn't able to get the relationships between tables in each Datasource. How can I write the query to extract the relationships metadata?

I need to get the GraphQL, how to extract the relationships between tables